# TypeError: child watchers are only available on the default loop

Tags: python

I have a piece of code as below python code:-

```
with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
    L = manager.list()
    number_processes = int(max(min(multiprocessing.cpu_count(), math.ceil(len(splittedFrames)/10.0)),1))
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(number_processes)
    workFunc = partial(multiProcWork, dictMVUserMapping, diColMapping, L)
    results = pool.map_async(workFunc, splittedFrames)
    results.get()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    # print L
    masterDictList = [x for x in L]
```

Which fails with below error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wiproadmin/Python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/wiproadmin/Python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/wiproadmin/Python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/wiproadmin/Python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/wiproadmin/Python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 138, in setMvMappingFields
    data = fn.uiDriverFunction(userMapping,token,username,provName=providerName)
  File "../bin/functionsForUI.py", line 499, in uiDriverFunction
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
  File "/home/wiproadmin/Python2713/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 99, in Manager
    m.start()
  File "/home/wiproadmin/Python2713/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 524, in start
    self._process.start()
  File "/home/wiproadmin/Python2713/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "/home/wiproadmin/Python2713/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.pid = os.fork()
  File "/home/wiproadmin/Python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/os.py", line 419, in fork
    return fork_and_watch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wiproadmin/Python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/os.py", line 375, in fork_and_watch
    watcher = loop.child(pid, ref=ref)
  File "gevent.libev.corecext.pyx", line 518, in gevent.libev.corecext.loop.child (src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:7603)
  File "gevent.libev.corecext.pyx", line 1886, in gevent.libev.corecext.child.__init__ (src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:21688)
TypeError: child watchers are only available on the default loop
```

Which is working fine in windows and failing in ubuntu machine version 14.04, Tried searching around, couldnt find any information.

Comment: You are most likely running this code in a `gevent` thread that is not your main thread. There is some information about that limitation on http://www.gevent.org/gevent.subprocess.html - "Caution On POSIX platforms, this module is not usable from native threads other than the main thread; attempting to do so will raise a TypeError."

Comment: Thanks for the help, resolved the issue :)

Comment: in some cases this error may also be avoided with gevent<1.1 (`$ sudo pip install 'gevent<1.1'`)